# Regex Search and replace, if between ," and ", is a comma

Tags: regex, vba

How can i in Visual Basic replace comma to dot

If between `,"` and `",` is a `comma` replace to `dot`

For example in first row replace `"482,5"` to `"482.5"`

```
"Peter",1,1,1,1,500,"500",631,"631",19,"482,5",1
"Peter",1,1,1,1,500,"500",631,"631",19,"482,5",2
"Peter",1,1,1,1,1984,"1984",635,"635",4,"101,5",3
"Peter",1,1,1,1,500,"500",2000,"2000",19,"482,5",4
"Peter",1,1,1,1,500,"500",1962,"1962",18,"457",5
"Peter",1,1,1,1,486,"486",613,"613",18,"457",6
"Peter",1,1,1,1,1016,"1016",322,"322",19,"482,5",7
"Peter",1,1,1,1,933,"933",444,"444",16,"406,5",8
"Peter",1,1,1,1,250,"250",476,"476",16,"406,5",9
"Peter",1,1,1,1,250,"250",476,"476",16,"406,5",10
"Peter",1,1,1,1,234,"234",933,"933",16,"406,5",11
"Peter",1,1,1,1,250,"250",965,"965",16,"406,5",12
```

Comment: scan each line incrementing a counter when you see the first ", decrementing it when you see another " and so on.  If you see a , on your walk and the counter > 0 then your inside quotes and you can replace.

Comment: Do you mean VB.NET or VBA? If VBA, is it Excel VBA?

Comment: VBA but not excel

Comment: Then, what is it? How this data is stored?

Comment: Cad/Cam software export a file to postprocesor, but before its finished i can  run a vb macro direct from software and change the comma to dot

Comment: _If VBA, is it Excel VBA?_  You mean, "if VBA, is it Excel-hosted VBA?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I suggest to parse the csv with a CSV parser because the CSV format is way more complicated than it seems to be. Just see [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) for details. The ideal solution would identify the problematic columns, and then replace the text in those columns only.

The regex approach must make some assumptions. I.e. the regex approach will work in some cases, and will not work in others.

Probably some people can write a really advanced regex that handles csvs correctly. But they are hard to understand and difficult to maintain. Let's just make assumptions here:

1. The only text delimiter that we care about is `"`. I.e. no `'` -s.
2. There are no quotes within fields. They would look like this: `"asd""ghi"`. Here is a more confusing example: `"asd"","`.

So the regex is:

```
(?:^|,)"[^",]*,
```

And the replacement is: `$1.`

Explanation:

- `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group
- `(?:^|,)` matches either start of line, or a comma
- then comes the `"` to match the starting quote
- `[^",]*` matches everything that's neither a quote or a comma. So it prevents matching through several fields.
- finally, it matches a comma: `,`
- the parentheses `(...)` capture the stuff inside. I.e. everything before the comma.
- In the replacement `$1` refers to the captured group. I.e. the replacement is the matched stuff, and then a dot. The closing comma was not in the group, so this is how the replacement goes.

[**RegexR demo**](https://regexr.com/3nktq).

[**VB.Net fiddle demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1kAP5H).

Comment: this regex is working, but just now have 1 or many commas teher, Is it possible to replace all commas beteween double quotes to dots?? thank you